# can't reinstall Firefox

Tags: package-management, firefox, dpkg

upgrated from Ubuntu 22. 04 to Ubuntu 22.10;;
Firefox broke down by updating;
deleted Firefox;
tried to reinstall Firefox;
recived many in Terminal: Cannot perform the following tasks: -snap firefox (25908); error: /var/cach/apt/archivesfirefox_1%3asnap 1-ubuntu2_amd64.deb. libdvd-pkg: 'ap-get check' failed, you may have broken packages. Abortig.
Is there any help?

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the entire output.